# mysql - move top scores to a new table from "scores" to "topscores"

Tags: mysql

I have a table "scores" with the following structure:

```
name, lastname, arena, level, time
example records:
john, wayne, forest_arena, 3, 12.33
john, wayne, forest_arena, 2, 13.49
john, wayne, forest_arena, 7, 11.40
```

As you can see, each arena can have several levels.

My question: How do i move all the fastest times for each level into a new table "topscores"?

I want the new table to contain ALL the fastest times for each arena + level, keeping the same structure as the first table.

Comment: insert into tableDestination(col1,col2, ... ) select colA,colB, ... from tableSource (where etc, join etc)

Comment: your question could use some improvement. Interpretation issues can be see below in answers (such as periodic triggers, events, one-time-shot, et al)

Comment: Why not a view? (As the other lad2025 suggested :p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CREATE TABLE ... AS` when creating first time:

```
CREATE TABLE topscores AS
SELECT name, lastname, arena, `level`, time
FROM scores s
WHERE (arena, `level`, time) IN (
   SELECT arena, `level`, MIN(time) AS `time`
   FROM scores
   GROUP BY arena, `level`);
```

Probably the better way is to create view (no need to update or refresh):

```
CREATE VIEW topscores
AS
SELECT name, lastname, arena, `level`, time
FROM scores s
WHERE (arena, `level`, time) IN (
   SELECT arena, `level`, MIN(time) AS `time`
   FROM scores
   GROUP BY arena, `level`);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee33a/1/0)**</kbd>